# Why doesn't find return the element as key for case?

Tags: common-lisp

In the following case statement, x was setf to #\j, yet "bye" is returned.

```
(case (find #\j "joy") ((x) (princ "hi")) (otherwise (princ "bye")))
```

find is supposed to return #\j, which should match x, right?

Answer (score 5):

Let's have a look.

```
CL-USER 2 > (setf x #\j)
#\j

CL-USER 3 > (case (find #\j "joy") ((x) (princ "hi")) (otherwise (princ "bye")))
bye
"bye"
```

Simplify: let's get rid of the `FIND`.

```
CL-USER 4 > (case #\j ((x) (princ "hi")) (otherwise (princ "bye")))
bye
"bye"
```

Does not work. Simplify: don't `PRINC`.

```
CL-USER 5 > (case #\j ((x) (princ "hi")) (otherwise "bye"))
"bye"
```

Does not work. Simplify: don't `PRINC`.

```
CL-USER 6 > (case #\j ((x) "hi") (otherwise "bye"))
"bye"
```

Does not work. We have a small expression. `CASE` is a macro. Let's expand the form:

```
CL-USER 7 > (macroexpand '(case #\j ((x) "hi") (otherwise "bye")))
(LET ((#:G1084 #\j))
  (COND ((OR (EQL (QUOTE X) #:G1084)) "hi")
        (T "bye")))
T
```

Oh, `X` is quoted and not evaluated. So you are testing if the character `#\j` is equal to the symbol `X`. This fails.

`CASE` does not evaluate the keys.

Solutions: either use something like `COND` or write a macro which hides something like `COND`. This has been written many times as an exercise.

```
CL-USER 8 > (let ((value (find #\j "joy")))
              (cond ((eql value x) "hi")
                    (t "bye")))
"hi"
```

Answer (score 3):

Clause keys are not evaluated, so the clause`((x)...)` will just match the symbol `x`.  That is the whole point of *case*: the keys are constant so the form can be compiled to produce more efficient code.  If you want dynamic keys then use association list, hash-table, etc.